# Apple ID recovery mail going to wrong email address

Tags: icloud, password, apple-id

I tried the forgot Apple ID / password option available on the Apple's site and selected the Reset via Email option. But the recovery e-mail they are sending to has got domain part wrong. As in `m*****@m*****.com` instead of `m*****@gmail.com`.

[image]

What can be wrong here? Is this some kind of a bug?

Comment: Hey There! We need more information. 1. which Link did you go to? 2. If it is iforgot, it asks for email address, then it asked me for a phone number linked to the ID. What did it ask to you? 3. A day has passed, have you reset your password successfully yet?

Comment: Still unsuccessful. Since it's an iPad I didn't link it to any phone number. I am not even sure of I remember what my security questions were because I have never before encountered a problem such as forgetting my password so I usually neglect all the security settings I add on them. Well I guess when you get too sloppy you learn your lesson, the hard way. I will try contacting Apple Support and see if there is any other way to recover this. Anyways thank you for your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple ID ask for a recovery email, so if you entered that other email as part of security and setup, this is expected information to progress through the automated reset procedure.

Additionally, if someone else guessed or got your password, they may have changed things. If you're really stuck after thinking this through and reading carefully the steps and being sure you are doing all the steps - in the order asked from:

- https://iforgot.apple.com

Then your next step would be to contact support to make sure you don't have any other avenues to reset the password. Hopefully there is another item you set up like security questions or a second authorization factor or telephone number.

Usually you don't lose all access to an Apple ID unless you lose or forget two different pieces of the information you entered. Most cases you get three different avenues for resetting a password.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about [iforgot](https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid), you must have entered the email address wrong in the page before the one in the screenshot. Please recheck.

Comment: But I forgot my password. And I usually just run through the initial setup process with all the information. The only thing I carefully enter is my email and password. And I am pretty sure I entered it with @gmail.com.

Comment: @HomeSpace Please tell me the Link you are using to reset the password.